# Allow User to Delete File In Use By My Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, filesystems

Can I allow a user to delete a file, under Windows, that is in use by my application?

In my scenario I have a "quick add" directory that is monitored by my application.  When it sees a new image show up it creates a new slide to display in an automated slide show.  I would also like to allow my users to delete (and/or rename) a file from my "quick add" directory, and remove it from the slide show.

Is there a way I can flag the file that notifies Windows that I'm okay for it to remove the file while my application is using it?

Comment: Are your users deleting/renaming files via the UI or manually from the folder?

Comment: They would be doing it from the folder.  So someone could, for example, push a new image in over the network just by dropping the file into the directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way I can flag the file that notifies Windows that I'm okay for it to remove the file while my application is using it?

Yes.  In Win32 this is `dwShareMode` passed to [`CreateFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx).  This is a bitfield of what you would like to permit another process to do.  The bit you are looking for is `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` which allows a delete or a rename while open.  However, for the most polite behavior I would recommend including all 3, `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE`.<sup>[1]</sup>

Since you're asking about C# and not Win32, in the .NET world these are included in the [`FileShare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx) enumeration which you can pass when opening a file, eg. in [`File.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725.aspx).

Note that these flags don't let you allow a rename of a file's parent directory while it is opened by name.  That will fail regardless of sharing due to limitations in the kernel (technically in ntfs.sys IIRC).

---

<sup>Footnote</sup>

<sup>1: Editorial comment: It is a shame that passing `0` (which many people do without thinking) happens to be the least permissive option, or that more people writing code on Windows don't realize what this parameter does and pass these three flags.</sup>

Comment: Sounds perfect.  I did not mention that the files are being opening via a `Source` attribute of an `Image` object - I am just passing the full path string.  Is there a way to send this flag to the `Image` tag when passing the image path string?  Thank you!

Comment: @EvilClosetMonkey - I don't know, but here's an idea: Call `File.Open` to get a `Stream`, then set the `Image`'s `ImageSource` to something set up with this property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource.aspx - be sure to close the file at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If you call a `Delete()` or `Rename()` method onto the Control that is using the file, you can remove it from the PictureBox before it deletes or renames the file.

There shouldn't be much of an issue with doing multiples. With a Checkbox on the Control, you just check each Control to see if that property is true, then call the appropriate method.